# Spring Data JPA Repository, exposed as REST resource suddenly becomes Unavailable, throws 404 Not Found Status

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa

I've created a JpaRepository like this one:

```java
    package com.app.repository;

    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    import com.app.entity.SampleEntity;

    @Repository
    @RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "exposed-uri", 
        path = "exposed-uri")
    public interface SampleEntityRepository 
        extends JpaRepository<SampleEntityRepository, Integer> { 

    }
```

And my entity is something like this:

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "SAMPLETABLE")
    public class SampleEntity {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "ID")
        private Integer id;
        @Column(name = "OTHER")
        private String otherField;
        @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
        private String description;

        //Some non-relevant boilerplate     
    }
```

My issue is that, and I don't understand a possible cause,... sometimes the resource becomes unavailable for the client application, receiving a 404 error status, just like if the exposed repository REST resource was not running. Other ones declared in @RestController classes in the application are still reachable and working properly.

My workaround in this case is to restart the SpringBoot application, but obviously that won't be acceptable for our customers.

Has someone faced this issue without needing to refactor your REST services to stop using the ones exposed from JpaRepositories? Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: can you share your controller?

Comment: @dasunse there is no explicit controller. The `@RepositoryRestResource` annotation in JPA repository exposes it as a REST resource.